# How do make a list of strings and then pick out a random string from the list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm making a program where I need all of the states and a random state must be chosen to ask the user to give the capital. How do I make a list to store all of these states and then have a random state chosen?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried reading some documentation about arrays and `java.util.Random`?

Comment: `list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())`; where `random` is an instance of `java.util.Random` and `list` is your list of states (a `java.util.List`)

Answer (score 5):

Add String to a list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
```

Generate a random number between 0 and the size of the list using

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(list.size()) ;
```

Get your String

```
String text = list.get(index);
```

Comment: When I try adding something to the list, I get an error by add saying that there was an identifier expected

Comment: Can you provide more details (eg the error and your code) ? This code works (tested)

Comment: import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class USStatesGame
{
    List<String> uSStates = new ArrayList<>();
    uSStates.add("Alabama");
}

Comment: the error that I'm getting is that it is saying by add an identifier is expected